# Ubuntu 18.04 uses only one processor core, but recognises all 4

Tags: kernel, intel, cpu

I noticed a huge drop in performance compared to Windows after dualbooting Ubuntu, and it turns out it's only using one of my CPU cores: [Here is the system monitor graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3iSc.png)

Running `lscpu` shows me that all 2 cores and 2 threads are recognised:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               94
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz
Stepping:            3
CPU MHz:             3700.002
CPU max MHz:         3700.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            7392.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

The other cores are still somewhat in use, but is there a reason why only one of them does most of the job? If you need any more info listed, please ask.

EDIT: I ran a stress test and it managed to get the other cores to 100%, so I'm guessing it's an issue of Ubuntu putting all small tasks into one core, without realising it overburdens it as one point. It's making the UI very stuttery and unusable.

Comment: Do you have a system resource monitor of some type you can provide output/screenshots of, or perhaps aggregate output of the `top` command? Alternatively, you could run something like `ps axo pid,psr,comm,user,pcpu --sort=-%cpu` if you want point in time CPU statistics. Applications can be single threaded and it may have nothing to do with Ubuntu itself.

In order to help determine what is causing the undesirably high resource utilization, more information would be extremely useful in order to help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: Not all code can take advantage of multiple cores, some being written and relies on things occurring in sequence thus can only use a single thread.   This is being changed in later releases of GNOME, see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/boosting-the-real-time-performance-of-gnome-shell-3-34-in-ubuntu-19-10 and possibly is your issue (ie. it's not a Ubuntu issue, but a limitation of the program you're looking at; eg. GNOME single-threading is being improved in later releases which @vanvugt discussed)

Comment: The issue persists even with no applications open. Running top tells me that a process named kworker/0:1-kac is using up 94% of the CPU. All other processes are normal